# Ternary operator sort syntax can't work in laravel blade

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

**laravel blade ternary operator**

```
 {{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

we can write short form

```
{{ $name or 'Default' }}
```

but it returns the Boolean value when implement like:

```
 {{$videos->count() or 'no video' }} //if count return 1 always,
```

but this code

```
  {{ $videos->count()}} // return 4
```

how to implement this by short form in blade ternary operator

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: php 7.1 and Laravel 5.4 using

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the count if it's > 0. Else you want to show the text.

Your `count()` is always `not null` (0 or higher). So what you want to do is this:

`{{$videos->count() > 0 ? $vides->count() : 'no video'}}`

Comment: This can be made shorter by using PHP 7 operators. Please see my answer.

Comment: @JoshBolton I don't think so, because `count()` is never null.

Answer (score 0):

Seen as you are using PHP 7.1 you can use the new Null Coalescing Operator. 
All PHP 7's new features can be found in the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Your code would then look like this:

```
{{$videos->count() ?? 'no video' }}
```

There is a detailed description of the operator in the docs:

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: `count()` is 0 or higher, never null.